# Replicating values in SAS by group

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I have a data set containing a measurement and the specific day it was collected. I would like to replicate the values between days, up until the last measurement day. For example, here is the data before it is replicated:

```
           Measurement    Day
Subject1   .85            -1
Subject1   .86            1            
Subject1   .91            7            
Subject1   .83            9            
Subject2   .77            0            
Subject2   .82            5            
Subject2   .86            12
```

I would like to modify the data set above to look like the following:

```
           Measurement    Day
Subject1   .85            -1
Subject1   .85            0
Subject1   .86            1
Subject1   .86            2
Subject1   .86            3
Subject1   .86            4
Subject1   .86            5 
Subject1   .86            6           
Subject1   .91            7
Subject1   .91            8            
Subject1   .83            9            
Subject2   .77            0
Subject2   .77            1
Subject2   .77            2
Subject2   .77            3
Subject2   .77            4       
Subject2   .82            5          
Subject2   .82            6
Subject2   .82            7     
Subject2   .82            8     
Subject2   .82            9     
Subject2   .82            10
Subject2   .82            11                      
Subject2   .86            12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a 'look ahead merge' by offsetting the merged data by one row, and omitting the `by` statement;

(assumes your data is sorted by Subject and Day)

```
data merge1 ;
  merge have
        have (rename=(day=nextday subject=nextsubject) drop=measurement firstobs=2) ;

  if subject = nextsubject then do _day = day to nextday - 1 ;
    output ;
  end ;
  else do ;
    _day = day ;
    output ;
  end ;

  drop day nextday nextsubject ;
  rename _day = day ;
run ;
```

Comment: Cool. You can use a single DO loop and no need for _DAY variable.  `do day = day by 1 until (day+1 > nextday);`

Comment: Need `keep=day subject` dataset option on second reference to HAVE to prevent overwriting measurement variable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider expanding data using a *helper* dataset, followed by left join `merge` with forward fill.

```
data helper;
    set input (keep = Subject Day);
    by Subject;
    if not first.Subject and last.Subject;

    max_day = max(Day);
    day = 0;
    do until(day > max_day);
      output;
      day + 1;
    end;

    drop max_day;
run;

data output;
    merge helper (in=h)
          input (in=i);
    if h;
    by Subject Day;

    retain _k;
    if not missing(Measurement) then _k=Measurement;
    else if missing(Measurement) then Measurement=_k;

    if not missing(Measurement);
    drop _k;
run;
```

**data**

```
data input;
    infile datalines delimiter=',' DSD; 
    length subject $ 10;

    input subject measurement day;
    datalines;
Subject1,.86,1 
Subject1,.91,7 
Subject1,.83,9 
Subject2,.77,0 
Subject2,.82,5 
Subject2,.86,12
;
```

**output**

```
Obs  subject   day   measurement 
1   Subject1     1          0.86 
2   Subject1     2          0.86 
3   Subject1     3          0.86 
4   Subject1     4          0.86 
5   Subject1     5          0.86 
6   Subject1     6          0.86 
7   Subject1     7          0.91 
8   Subject1     8          0.91 
9   Subject1     9          0.83 
10  Subject2     0          0.77 
11  Subject2     1          0.77 
12  Subject2     2          0.77 
13  Subject2     3          0.77 
14  Subject2     4          0.77 
15  Subject2     5          0.82 
16  Subject2     6          0.82 
17  Subject2     7          0.82 
18  Subject2     8          0.82 
19  Subject2     9          0.82 
20  Subject2     10         0.82 
21  Subject2     11         0.82 
22  Subject2     12         0.86
```

Comment: Just tried using this. This results in a subject's final becoming the next subject's first weight. Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you run my solution with the data I include for reproducibility, outputs match your desired result with different column order. Maybe your actual data is different than posted example.

Comment: Yes, I am working with a new data set. Maybe I should be more concise: the code results in the next subject's first number being overwritten by the previous subject's final measurement. Also, if the number in the 'Day' column is negative this does not work.

Comment: Once again, this solution matches your posted desired result. The first record of Subject 2 has measurement of 0.77 on Day 0 which is exactly as is in input data. Your sample did not include negative days which I likely would have factored in. In future, please post close to actual data!

Comment: I updated the data to include a negative value for the 'Day' variable. I think it would just take a slight modification of the code to fix.

Comment: Is desired result supposed to change too? As of now, adding that one record with negative day in my input data, I return exactly the same result as before. Subject 2 still starts at Day 0 with 0.77 msmt.

Comment: Strange. I have used your code and just swapped the variables, but the last value for Subject 1 is overwriting the first value for Subject 2 every time. I need the day counter to stop on the last day, and apparently it is counting one additional day. I will try to find the fix.

Comment: Please run my reproducible example (first run the data portion for *input* then actual code at top).