# keep only consecutive rows that match the requirement in sas eg

Tags: sas, rows

I am new in SAS EG, I would like to know how can I keep only consecutive rows that match my condition. Sample dateset below.

```
+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  Date   | Customer | Contract_No | Centre_code |
+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| 10Jul19 | AAAAA    | AAAAA1234   |         319 |
| 11Jul19 | AAAAA    | AAAAA1234   |         319 |
| 10Jul19 | AAAAA    | AAAAA5678   |         319 |
| 11Jul19 | AAAAA    | AAAAA5678   |         319 |
| 10Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB1234   |         515 |
| 11Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB1234   |         515 |
| 10Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB1234   |         515 |
| 11Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB1234   |         515 |
| 10Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB11878  |         511 |
| 11Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB11878  |         515 |
| 10Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB48741  |         511 |
| 11Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB48741  |         515 |
+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

I want only to keep the records that Centre code has changed on the consecutive date per Contract No.

Desire output

```
+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  Date   | Customer | Contract_No | Centre_code |
+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| 10Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB11878  |         511 |
| 11Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB11878  |         515 |
| 10Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB48741  |         511 |
| 11Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB48741  |         515 |
+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Desire output

```
+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  Date   | Customer | Contract_No | Centre_code |
+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| 10Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB11878  |         511 |
| 11Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB11878  |         515 |
| 10Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB48741  |         511 |
| 11Jul19 | BBBBB    | BBBBB48741  |         515 |
+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a clever solution posed under [Replicating values in SAS by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205986/replicating-values-in-sas-by-group)

```
proc sort data = have;
  by contract_no date;
run;

data changed;
  merge have 
         have (firstobs = 2 rename = (date=date_next code = code_next customer=customer_next contract_no = contract_no_next));

  retain output_next_flag 0;

  if (contract_no = contract_no_next and date_next - date = 1 and code ~= code_next) then do;
    output_next_flag = 1;
    output;
  end;
  else if output_next_flag then do;
    output;
    output_next_flag = 0;
  end;
  else output_next_flag = 0;

  keep date customer code contract_no;

run;
```

Comment: Your given codes doesn't return any observations. I have modified the table in questions. I would appreciate if you can help me to get only rows that Centre_code changed from two consecutive rows.

Comment: Can you share the log please

Comment: It shows 0 observations. What I want to show are those Contract_no that Centre_code changed in two consecutive date.

Comment: I was able to produce the results you wanted with this code. Did you make sure the columns names are the same since I used slightly different names for columns. Sharing the log will help locate the exact issue.

Comment: I can't attached the screenshot however below is what Description says in the Log Summary. 
DESCRIPTION
NOTE: wRITING TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file:EGSR
WARNING: Unsupported device 'ACTIVEX' for EXCEL(EGXLSSX) destination. Using device 'ACTXIMG'.
NOTE: No observations in data set Work.Fact_Acct.
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
NOTE: Writing EXCEL(EGXLSSX) file:/saswork/sasworkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: This part of the log does not correspond to this part of the code. Please show the log corresponding to this code